# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eglGetCurrentContext'

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl, egl

I am having a problem with python and `pyopengl`
I am just importing the modules, and getting errors, I checked and pip did install opengl and everything.

Here is my code

```
# ulWindow
import ulMath as ulm
import OpenGL.GL as gl
import OpenGL.GlE as gle
import glfw

def init() ->int|str:
     if (not glfw.init()):
          return "GLFW Failed to initialize"
     return 0
```

And the error im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/ulWindow.py", line 3, in <module>
    import OpenGL.GL as gl
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL.VERSION.GL_1_1 import *
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/VERSION/GL_1_1.py", line 14, in <module>
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.VERSION.GL_1_1 import *
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GL/VERSION/GL_1_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    from OpenGL.raw.GL import _errors
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/raw/GL/_errors.py", line 4, in <module>
    _error_checker = _ErrorChecker( _p, _p.GL.glGetError )
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/error.py", line 183, in __init__
    self._isValid = platform.CurrentContextIsValid
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 15, in __get__
    value = self.fget( obj )
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 356, in CurrentContextIsValid
    return self.GetCurrentContext
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 15, in __get__
    value = self.fget( obj )
  File "/home/jack3/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/egl.py", line 106, in GetCurrentContext
    return self.EGL.eglGetCurrentContext
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'eglGetCurrentContext'
```

I have absolutely no clue what is going on, can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide debugging details. What is your platform? The pyopengl tried the EGL, but it's not what you want in most cases.